# Splitting Reactive Stream into 2 Streams then merging them again using a corralation id?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactive, spring-reactor

UserStory:

Imaginge i have

A group of schools with students

A Bus Company that owns many buses for rental

And each school may rent a bus from the bus company

- 1 or more school can rent the same bus from the bus company

And given that the school bus is working, a school fetches groups of 10 students at a time and consider that all these trips happens instantenously to the school ( IE : if the bus is working then all students reach there respective schools in no time )

Problem Statement

- I have a stream of schools and i need to split School stream into two streams

  1. A stream of groups of students for each School
  2. A stream of buses
- Then for the stream of buses i need to remove the broken buses from the stream , so i can have a stream of working school buses
- Finally i need to remerge the two stream ( Stream of groups of schools and Stream of buses ) given a corallation id ( IE : Group of students belonging to school x can use bus Y that is valid for usage by school x )
- Notes

  - The solution must be in java
  - Preferably i am using Reactor project but feel free to use RXJava
  - Thank you for sparing time in helping me in such a problem :)

Comment: Could you please provide some code example like classes/ interfaces and the obeservable stream itself?

Comment: need to see your models at least